# Comparing two contingency tables

Tags: excel, spss, contingency

I have two 6x4 contingency tables for frequency data. They are based on the same type of sampling criteria of a number of discreet variables but for two condition (before and after). I would like to compare these statistcally to see how much - or not - they differ.

A Chi square related test seems appropriate but normally this gives a result in comparison to the theoretical to calculate the statistic. So in other words I need to swap the theoretical for the second table. Of course it doesn't have to be a basic chi square test - any other appropriate test would be ok.

I have access to XLSTAT, Excel and SPSS. And would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: If you are looking for a place to start, start with **R** see [tag:r].

Comment: The question seems more theoretical than technical, doesn't it? Technically you can go ahead and use `Chisq.Test` between the two tables but the problem is how you would interpret the result since none of them is the "expected" table. In that case I think that this question is more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com. By the way the same question about interpreting the result will remain whatever the technical method and the tool that you use.

Comment: Well, technical in one sense inasmuch as it's a while since I've used Chi sq. So, based on what you've said, would I be right in saying (if the utility can do it) that you would put one table in as the observed frequencies and the other as the expected frequencies? Otherwise how would you practically do run a test? As far as interpretation, really all I want to determine at the point is whether the 'patterns' of the tables are significantly different. However, I do take the point about it's theoretical nature.

Comment: Since, posting this I've attempted to use a log linear approach. However, as you mentioned, Brian, interpretation is difficult. Nevertheless, I've used the Vassar utility (http://vassarstats.net/abc.html). But I'm not sure if this is the answer, as it seems to give me the interactions, though what I'm after is a comparison of the two table's patterns to test significance- if that's possible. I'm also wondering what the story is here if the frequencies are very low (like 0 and 1 at the extreme). Having said that, it might be the same thing, but I'm not clear. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI tried posting on stats.stackexchange, by the way, but received no responses.